# Docx to HTML using phpdocx

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, ms-word

I'm having troubles with transforming .docx to html...
I'm using [PHPDOCX FREE](http://www.phpdocx.com/download) to handle this problem...
I have some problems with it and I was able to determine where the problem was..
it's in the next piece of code:

```
$xmlDOM = new DOMDocument();
$xml = str_replace('</w:wordDocument>', '', $xml);
$xml = preg_replace(
  '/(<w:wordDocument)+(.)*(><w:body>)/', '<w:body>', $xml
 );
```

escpecially in the 'preg_replace' function...
it's making the server so busy... so I can't work anything until I restart the server...

Comment: your document is very large ?

Comment: As salaamu alaikum @Ibrahim.I ... can you share me your working code.. i am too having trouble with this issue.. thanks in advance..

Comment: @786 are you still there? contact me on my e-mail "ibrah.ibra@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this :

```
$xml = preg_replace(
  '/(<w:wordDocument)+(.)*(><w:body>)/', '<w:body>', $xml
 );
```

By this :

```
$xml = preg_replace(
  '/<w:wordDocument.*?><w:body>/', '<w:body>', $xml
 );
```

Or just (if the wordDocument tag is always folowed by body tag) :

```
$xml = preg_replace(
  '/<w:wordDocument.*?>/', '', $xml
 );
```

Using parentheses makes php use more mamory.
Wich PHP version you got ?

Comment: I replaced it with the first choice and it works... but unfortunately it didn't give me what I want...
it's giving unformatted html file...
in the generated html code there are css classes which I don't know where they came from...
like Title-P and Heading1-P and ListParagraph-P...etc
any help??

Comment: Can't help you more (I never yoused that library), but I think they are generated with that library to format the writing (you see the styles you use in the word doc get transformed to css styles)

Comment: that's the problem... there is no css file containing these classes...
anyway thank u so much...